# iPhone Apps section not showing up in iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I'm using the latest iTunes 12.7 and iPhone software (iOS 10.3.3). Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

iTunes 12.7 removes the App Store and iOS apps sync functionality.

> If you previously used iTunes to sync apps, books, or ringtones to your iOS device, use the new App Store, iBooks, or Sounds Settings on iOS to redownload them without your computer.

https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1814